# MS Access Data to Combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, combobox

i have a form i'm using for editing data, when i select an id, it shows some data in my `textboxes`, i would like also to show some data into my `position_edit` combobox.
this is my code so far :

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE ID = '" + id_edit.Text + "'";
    command.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        name_edit.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
        dob_edit.Text = reader["DOB"].ToString();
        position_edit.Items.Add ??
    }
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
    connection.Close();
}
```

thanks.

Comment: You can use `position_edit.Items.Add(reader["FieldName"].ToString())`, but I do not know what is the data you want to display in combobox ?

Comment: FYI - This is a TEXTBOOK SQL-Injection vulnerability.  Good read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx